# Can you use ipywidgets outside Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, user-interface, jupyter, ipywidgets, graphical-interaction

Is there a way to write a standalone ipywidgets based GUI that doesn't rely on a hosting Jupyter notebook, i.e., that can be displayed from a regular python script?

I know about Voila and tkinter, and neither is what I want.

Comment: Panel has widgets too that run in WASM directly in the browser. See [here](https://twitter.com/JupyterTutorial/status/1584440212113231872) and links therein. There's examples using Panel [here](https://pyscript.net/examples/), [a couple under 'Pandas dataframe input and display' here](https://github.com/fomightez/pyscript_test#pandas-dataframe-input-and-display), and [here](https://amrrs.github.io/pyscript-upload-download-repl/).

Comment: I think I totally missed the 'regular python script' yesterday and was focusing on you wanting to avoid hosting. What I really think you might like:  There's [Qt Widgets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-index.html) and the related [PyQtGraph: Scientific Graphics and GUI Library for Python](https://www.pyqtgraph.org/). These don't need Jupyter and in fact were developed separately before there were ipywidgets, I believe.

Comment: @Wayne the reason I asked about ipywidgets is that i can easily display dataframes and plotly HTML charts with them. Can I do that with Qt too?

Comment: It looks to me like handling a Pandas dataframe isn't baked in to PyQt and that you have to build in the viewer handling yourself. The example in the documentation for doing that is [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/examples/example_external__pandas.html). There seems to be some alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58323607/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44603119/8508004). There seems to be examples of using Plotly with it, too. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57063046/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60523577/8508004) and ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60566087/8508004).